# JavaScript: "same-origin policy" failure

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I've tried innumerable permutations of code and the nearest I've gotten to success is a warning about the "same-origin policy", or I'm bounced to the sign-in page for the application, which is written using CodeIgniter.

For the sake of keeping this sensible, on domain-one.com, I'm using:

```
(function($) {
    var url = 'http://domain-two.com/get_data?callback=?';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In the PHP on domain-two.com, I'm using:

```
public function get_data () {
    $results = $this->model->method();
    if (count(results)>0):
        foreach (results as $array):
            $array['index'] = $array['value'];
            $array[] = $array_result;
        endforeach;

        header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

        $json = json_encode($array);

        # JSON if no callback
        if( ! $this->input->get('callback')):
            exit( $json );
        endif;
        # JSONP if valid callback
        if(is_valid_callback($this->input->get('callback'))):
            exit( $this->input->get('callback') . "(" . $json . ")" );
        endif;

    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

At this point, it's worth mentioning that when I visit the link for the PHP method, it gives me the data I need. If, however, I do so via the web page containing the JavaScript, it does not ("same-origin policy" error, or I'm bounced to the sign-in page).

Help regarding how I make use of a callback is, at best, scant (some advise using an actual callback function, others claim no such function is required).

After 5 days at this, I have no idea what I'm meant to be doing, given the sheer number of different techniques, none of which appear to work for me.

Any advice would be much welcome!

Comment: `bounced to the sign in page` sounds like you should be authenticating, but I don't see evidence of that in your code ?  Also, you should avoid the use of `async: false` as it is deprecated.  There are other ways to ensure you wait for the ajax call to complete, such as promises.

Comment: No, there's no authentication code in that controller. I think the callback is causing a problem for CodeIgniter and — perhaps — stripping out the URL parameter for the method.

If there are alternatives to `async`, now would be a good time to share.

Comment: use [promises](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php on `domain-two.com`

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain-one.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain-two.com');
```

Comment: Yeah, that also bounces me to the sign-in page.

Comment: In the end, after a bit of fooling around with the placement, this was the correct answer.